# Is there a program which can count occurrence of a certain string in a binary file?

Tags: linux, windows, search

I have a binary file and I need to count occurrences of certain string in this file or even list then with offsets. In Windows or Linux- for this task I use Fedora 12 and Windows 2000.

Comment: For Linux: `strings -a filename | grep string | wc -l`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Linux with [GNU grep](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/):

```
grep -F --text -o --byte-offset mystring binaryfile
```

Example:

```
$ grep -F --text -o --byte-offset option /bin/tar
226542:option
237529:option
237612:option
...
```

Explanation of the parameters:

```
-F, --fixed-strings
      Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines,
      any of which is to be matched.  (-F is specified by POSIX.)

-a, --text
      Process  a binary file as if it were text; this is equivalent to the
      --binary-files=text option.

-o, --only-matching
      Print  only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with
      each such part on a separate output line.

-b, --byte-offset
      Print the 0-based byte offset within the input file before each line
      of output. If -o (--only-matching) is specified, print the offset of
      the matching part itself
```

To count the occurrences add `| wc -l` to the command line.

Comment: Is it possible to get count only? I know I asked for offsets, but for the count too.

Comment: @IvanH: Just pipe it to `wc -l`

Comment: Good job including the other parameters!

Answer (score 2):

[Agent Ransack - Free File Searching Utility](http://www.mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=agentransack&page=home)

> - **Immediate results** Found text is shown with highlighted keywords    so you don't need to waste time opening each file looking for the
>     right information.
> - **Boolean expressions** Combine search terms using the familiar Boolean operators AND, OR, NOT.
> - **Office formats** Support for popular Office formats including Office 2007 and OpenOffice.
> - **Perl regex** Support for Perl compatible regular expressions.
> - **64-bit Version** Natively compiled 64-bit version for improved compatibility.
> - **Fast searching** Highly efficient search algorithms mean that you spend less time waiting for results.
> - **Printing and Exporting** Results can be shared with others through printing and exporting.

[image]

Comment: Can it handle a binary file?

Comment: Yes, it can handle binary values. See the screenshot, it has also found `dll` files.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, you can use `strings -a [filename] | grep [string] | wc -l`

In Windows, you can use the `strings * | findstr /i [string]`, with the [strings utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439) from Sysinternals.

Comment: How are multiple occurrences on the same line counted, as one or more?

Comment: Your answer says there are 39 occurrences of "option" in /bin/tar (`strings -a /bin/tar | grep option | wc -l`), while [mine](https://superuser.com/a/424845/2357) says 45 (`grep -F --text -o --byte-offset option /bin/tar | wc -l`).